# How would I make my social icons appear horizontally on mobile view?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm trying to make all of these social icons appear horizontally in a straight line mobile view but no matter what I try in my media query, nothing works.

The social icons appear horizontally with no problems when in desktop view.

Note: I'm using the same CSS that's outside the media query into the media query just to get the ball rolling, but it didn't work at all.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="socialIcons row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
@media only screen /* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */
and (min-device-width: 414px)
and (max-device-width: 736px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
and (orientation: portrait) {
 i.fa {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    width: 5.7em;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 43.5%;
}

i.fab {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    color: red;
    width: 5.7em;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 43.5%;
}

i.fa-linkedin {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    color: #0077B5;
    width: 5.7em;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 43.5%;
}
}
```

Comment: you could try something more dramatical like setting `background-color: deepskyblue;` to `i.fa` then you will see if the media query gets a hit. Try that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the Bootstrap classes that you're using for the horizontal alignment are not for extra small devices, the "col-sm-1" is for (min-width: 576px) and upper resolutions.

I assume your using Bootstrap 4, because they changed the class for col-xs-*.

Try use "col-1" instead of the one you're using.

Comment: Bingo, I appreciate it immensely!